# Failed to notify project evaluation listener. org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSetOutput.getClassesDir()Ljava/io/File;

Tags: java, android, gradle, task, backend

I am trying to run the task below

```
task startBackend(dependsOn: ':backend:appengineStart') {
    doLast {
        println 'App engine started'
    }
    task finalTask() {
        dependsOn 'startBackend'
        mustRunAfter 'startBackend'
        dependsOn ':app:connectedAndroidTest'
        finalizedBy ':backend:appengineStop'
    }
}
```

and i get the error in the title

```
`Failed to notify project evaluation listener.>org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.setBootClasspath(Ljava/lang/String;)V> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:endpointsServer'.problem occurred configuring project ':backend'.`
```

i have the 4.10.1 gradle version 
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip`

My test is passing btw.